ProtocolError: Page.captureScreenshot timed out after upgrading canary runtime to syn-nodejs-puppeteer-7.0
We've had, for a while, a canary script running on syn-nodejs-puppeteer-6.2 runtime with no issues whatsoever, but ever since we upgraded it to syn-nodejs-puppeteer-7.0 the canary function will occasionally throw the following error:
ERROR: Canary error: 
ProtocolError: Page.captureScreenshot timed out. Increase the 'protocolTimeout' setting in launch/connect calls for a higher timeout if needed.

ProtocolError image
This error usually gets thrown once or twice a day in the early morning hours and we are unsure how to reproduce it. We have tried increasing the Lambda memory size and the wait timeouts from within the code but nothing has helped.
Frequency of ProtocolError
The error message says to increase the 'protocolTimeout' setting in launch/connect but we can't access the browser initialization, as we are using the 'synthetics' library.
Our code is pasted below:
const { URL } = require('url');
const synthetics = require('Synthetics');
const log = require('SyntheticsLogger');
const syntheticsConfiguration = synthetics.getConfiguration();
const syntheticsLogHelper = require('SyntheticsLogHelper');

const loadBlueprint = async function () {

//around 10 urls to check
    const urls = ["https://www.test_url_1.com"];

    // Set screenshot option
    const takeScreenshot = true;

    /* Disabling default step screen shots taken during Synthetics.executeStep() calls
     * Step will be used to publish metrics on time taken to load dom content but
     * Screenshots will be taken outside the executeStep to allow for page to completely load with domcontentloaded
     * You can change it to load, networkidle0, networkidle2 depending on what works best for you.
     */
    syntheticsConfiguration.disableStepScreenshots();
    syntheticsConfiguration.setConfig({
       continueOnStepFailure: true,
       includeRequestHeaders: true, // Enable if headers should be displayed in HAR
       includeResponseHeaders: true, // Enable if headers should be displayed in HAR
       restrictedHeaders: [], // Value of these headers will be redacted from logs and reports
       restrictedUrlParameters: [] // Values of these url parameters will be redacted from logs and reports

    });

    let page = await synthetics.getPage();

    // for (const url of urls) {
    //     await loadUrl(page, url, takeScreenshot);
    // }
    
     await urls.reduce(async (previousUrl, url) => {
    // Wait for the previous loop to finish processing.
    await previousUrl;
    // finishes the current test.
    await loadUrl(page, url, takeScreenshot);
  }, Promise.resolve());
};

// Reset the page in-between
const resetPage = async function(page) {
    try {
        await page.goto('about:blank',{waitUntil: ['load', 'networkidle0'], timeout: 30000} );
    } catch (e) {
        synthetics.addExecutionError('Unable to open a blank page. ', e);
    }
}

const loadUrl = async function (page, url, takeScreenshot) {
    let stepName = null;
    let domcontentloaded = false;

    try {
        stepName = new URL(url).hostname;
    } catch (e) {
        const errorString = `Error parsing url: ${url}. ${e}`;
        log.error(errorString);
        /* If we fail to parse the URL, don't emit a metric with a stepName based on it.
           It may not be a legal CloudWatch metric dimension name and we may not have an alarms
           setup on the malformed URL stepName.  Instead, fail this step which will
           show up in the logs and will fail the overall canary and alarm on the overall canary
           success rate.
        */
        throw e;
    }

    await synthetics.executeStep(stepName, async function () {
        const sanitizedUrl = syntheticsLogHelper.getSanitizedUrl(url);

        /* You can customize the wait condition here. For instance, using 'networkidle2' or 'networkidle0' to load page completely.
           networkidle0: Navigation is successful when the page has had no network requests for half a second. This might never happen if page is constantly loading multiple resources.
           networkidle2: Navigation is successful when the page has no more then 2 network requests for half a second.
           domcontentloaded: It's fired as soon as the page DOM has been loaded, without waiting for resources to finish loading. If needed add explicit wait with await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, milliseconds))
        */
        const response = await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: ['domcontentloaded'], timeout: 30000});
        if (response) {
            domcontentloaded = true;
            const status = response.status();
            const statusText = response.statusText();

            logResponseString = `Response from url: ${sanitizedUrl}  Status: ${status}  Status Text: ${statusText}`;

            //If the response status code is not a 2xx success code
            if (response.status() < 200 || response.status() > 299) {
                throw new Error(`Failed to load url: ${sanitizedUrl} ${response.status()} ${response.statusText()}`);
            }
        } else {
            const logNoResponseString = `No response returned for url: ${sanitizedUrl}`;
            log.error(logNoResponseString);
            throw new Error(logNoResponseString);
        }
    });

    // Wait for 15 seconds to let page load fully before taking screenshot.
    if (domcontentloaded && takeScreenshot) {
        await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 15000));
        await synthetics.takeScreenshot(stepName, 'loaded');
    }
    
    // Reset page
    await resetPage(page);
};

exports.handler = async () => {
    return loadBlueprint();
};

If anyone has any experience with this we would greatly appreciate any kind of help 
We tried to increase the Lambda memory size, as well as its timeout from 3 minutes to 5. We have tried some minor code modifications as well, but nothing has helped.
